# Sqlalchemy: Query - get only the parents when all child's satisfy the inequality condition

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

i am new with databases and sqlalchemy and i am trying to make a query using an inequality condition, but it always return the parent aslong as one of the childs satisfy the condition and i need all the childs satisfy that inequality

My current tables:

```py
class Jefe(Base):
    """ Tabla de jefes"""

    __tablename__ = 'jefe'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    nombre = Column(String, unique=True)
    empleado = relationship('Empleado', backref='jefe', cascade='all, delete-orphan')


class Empleado(Base):
    """ Tabla de empleados"""

    __tablename__ = 'empleado'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    jefe_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('jefe.id'), nullable=False)
    nombre = Column(String, unique=True)
    salario = Column(Float)
```

my actual query:

```
result = Session.query(Jefe).join(Empleado).filter(Empleado.salario > 120).all()
```

which output is:

```
Jefe: Yehender carrasco --- id: 1 
 ----------- Empleados
 ----------- nombre: Jesus ramirez --- salario: 150.00 --- id: 1
 ----------- nombre: Erlinda pereira --- salario: 130.00 --- id: 2


Jefe: Kleiver carrasco --- id: 2 
 ----------- Empleados
 ----------- nombre: Jesus carvajal --- salario: 155.00 --- id: 3
 ----------- nombre: Victor araujo --- salario: 135.00 --- id: 4
 ----------- nombre: Cristhiam ochoa --- salario: 105.00 --- id: 9


Jefe: Ivan marquez --- id: 4 
 ----------- Empleados
 ----------- nombre: Eliana ortega --- salario: 145.00 --- id: 7
 ----------- nombre: Sofia marquez --- salario: 133.30 --- id: 8
```

And I want the second result not to appear given that cristhiam ochoa's salary is less than 120, like this:

```
Jefe: Yehender carrasco --- id: 1 
 ----------- Empleados
 ----------- nombre: Jesus ramirez --- salario: 150.00 --- id: 1
 ----------- nombre: Erlinda pereira --- salario: 130.00 --- id: 2


Jefe: Ivan marquez --- id: 4 
 ----------- Empleados
 ----------- nombre: Eliana ortega --- salario: 145.00 --- id: 7
 ----------- nombre: Sofia marquez --- salario: 133.30 --- id: 8
```

I know that I have to modify the filtering condition so that all the children are taken into account, but I do not know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting up your join properly. Try this:

```py
result = Session.query(Jefe).join(Jefe.empleado).filter(Empleado.salario > 120).all()
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,  modifying the query like you suggest, i get the same result , i get back the 3 bosses (Jefes)